# How are duplicated config entires resolved?

Tags: akka

Suppose I have created application config like this:

```
akka {
  loglevel = DEBUG
  loglevel = INFO
}
```

Is there an algorithm about resolving duplication properties in akka? Does akka select last value forever or choose property randomly? Or it ignore last property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Akka is using [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) as the config library. The language used in it is HOCON (read as Human Optimized Configuration Object Notation), and one of the language's rules states:

- Duplicate keys are allowed; later values override earlier, except for object-valued keys where the two objects are merged recursively

So yes, it's predictable which value will be picked up.

Comment: It's the mechanism (aka trick) to have a fallback to use a default value when there's no system property with the value of the property.